# Restoring terminal settings (termios) in signal handler

Tags: linux, terminal, signal-handling, termios

In a code which changes terminal settings (it embeds python, which in turn uses some terminal manipulating modules), the changed state persists after I quit via Ctrl-\ sending SIGQUIT to the process.

Is it safe to save terminal settings at startup, and then register SIGQUIT handler which will restore those? If not safe, what can happen at the worst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal handlers usually should be lean and not do much work. You shouldn't be calling non asynchronous-safe functions from signal-handler. [Async-signal-safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). So, if your termios code contains non AS functions, than restoration of terminal settings from signal-handler is not recommended ( Though you will be handling SIGQUIT)

How about this:

`fork()` is listed as AS safe in the man page of `signal`. Why not fork a child process, `execv` another program which will restore the settings?

Comment: Helpful answer, but I don't understand the first part: "is out of scope of your program"?? How do you know? It is totally within the scope, because other part of it changes terminal settings in the first place.

Comment: No. I meant, the changes will be persistent even after program terminates.   I was just re-iterating what you had mentioned. Have removed those statemetns